# Form elements not submitting after being opened in a modal

Tags: html, uikit

I have an HTML form, most of the elements of this are visible on a page in my application, but some of the elements are hidden away using a modal.

Here is a simplified form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Color</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <input class="uk-input uk-form-small" name="color" type="text" value="{{ @data[color] }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-select">Battery</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <select name="battery_hasbattery" class="uk-select uk-form-small">
                <option value="0">This device does NOT have a battery</option>
                <check if="{{ @data[battery_hasbattery] == 1 }}">
                    <true><option selected value="1">This device DOES have a battery</option></true>
                    <false><option value="1">This device DOES have a battery</option></false>
                </check>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">More Options</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <a href="#additional_options" uk-toggle class="uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">More Template Options</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="additional_options" uk-modal>
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
            <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Additional Template Options</h2>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-select">Needs Image</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                    <select name="need_image" class="uk-select uk-form-small">
                        <option value="0">This device does NOT need an image</option>
                        <check if="{{ @data[need_image] == 1 }}">
                            <true><option selected value="1">This device DOES need an image</option></true>
                            <false><option value="1">This device DOES need an image</option></false>
                        </check>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p class="uk-text-right">
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Close Window</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, in the form there is an `<a>` element which opens up the modal `#additional_options`. This modal is also contained inside the `<form>` tags.

If I submit this page ***without opening the modal***, I have verified that the fields inside the modal are still posting to the processing page.

But, if I open the modal, none of the elements inside the modal post to the processing page.

When I do Inspect Element on my modal, when it gets opened it is automatically moved to the bottom of my DOM, but I still need these values to POST when the form is submitted.

Obviously these elements don't do much good if they don't POST after being accessed, how can I make these fields still POST even if the modal has been opened?

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you know why it's happening - by yanking the fields out of the `<form/>` and putting them in the end of the page, they're no longer part of the form when you submit it.

You could keep the fields in the form all the time as hidden fields, and duplicate those fields with the modal.

With javascript, you can sync the modal's fields (which aren't in the form) with the hidden fields (which are in the form).

If you're not using a framework, you can do it with pure js, but a lot of js frameworks provide form value modeling abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using the [`form`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp) attribute on my form elements that are in the modal.

```
<select form="data_form" name="need_image" class="uk-select uk-form-small">
    ...
</select>
```

And assigning an ID to my form

```
<form method="POST" id="data_form">
```

Now, no matter where the form elements are on the page, they will  be submitted with my form.

Comment: That's a way simpler approach than my answer. Nice one!